# How to convert text file to a JSON file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which looks like this (myfile.txt)

```
GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO2  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYG3  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYG4  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYO5  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO6  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
```

I have to write this text content to a JSON file (myfile.json).
this is the expected output

```
[
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}
]
```

this is what I tried

I created a file called "textconvert.sh". then wrote a shell script like this.

```
echo"[" >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}, >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}, >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"}, >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"}, >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}, >> myfile.json
echo {"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"} >> myfile.json
echo"]" >> myfile.json
```

but I am not allowed to hard coding like this.
what I am thinking now is,

write a loop to scan "myfile.txt"
then assign column values to variables.
then write a json file.

Can someone help me to figure out this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    fmt = "%s{\"ApplicationName\":\"%s\",\"BuildBreakReason\":\"%s\",\"DefectAuthor\": \"%s\"}"
    print "["
}
{ printf fmt, sep, $2, $4, $3; sep="," ORS }
END { print ORS "]" }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk myfile.txt
[
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}
]
```

Regarding `What I am thinking now is, write a loop to scan "myfile.txt"...` from your question - no, don't do that. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 2):

Using sed

```
$ sed -E 's/[^ ]* +([^ ]*) +([^ ]*) +(.*)/{"ApplicationName":"\1","BuildBreakReason":"\3","DefectAuthor": "\2"},/;$s/,$/\n]/;1i[' myfile.txt
[
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor": "nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor": "james@qt.com"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working. I would like to know Is there any way to do this with "awk" command?

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
GYFUFGYO1  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO2  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYG3  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYG4  AFP-Login   nathan@qt.com  BUG
GYFUFGYO5  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
GYFUFGYO6  KMP-app   james@qt.com  CODE_SMELL
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "["}NR>1{print ","}{printf "{\"ApplicationName\":\"%s\",\"BuildBreakReason\":\"%s\",\"DefectAuthor\":\"%s\"}",$2,$4,$3}END{print "\n]"}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
[
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor":"james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor":"james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor":"nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"AFP-Login","BuildBreakReason":"BUG","DefectAuthor":"nathan@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor":"james@qt.com"},
{"ApplicationName":"KMP-app","BuildBreakReason":"CODE_SMELL","DefectAuthor":"james@qt.com"}
]
```

Explanation: You need `,` after every but last characters, but detecting last line in GNU `AWK` is not easy, so I `print` `,` before every but 1st record. I use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) to rework your whitespace-sheared records into JSON, 1st argument is string with places to fill denoted by `%s`, observe that `"` needs to be escaped to mean literal `"`. `BEGIN` and `END` are used to encase records into `[` and `]`. **Disclaimer**: this code does not espace characters of special meaning to JSON, for example `"`.

(tested in gawk 4.2.1)